# Add each file in documents folder to an array - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have an array

```
var items: [String] = []
```

I want to add each filename in documents folder to this array.

```
  var error = NSErrorPointer()
    let fldrs = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true) as? [String]
    if fldrs != nil {
        //???
    }
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: Look at the docs for `NSFileManager`.

Comment: does this question really deserve down vote ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by rmaddy you can use NSFileManager to list the contents of a directory using the URLsForDirectory method to get an array of urls and you can use map to extract only the last path component of those URLs:

```
let documentsUrl =  NSFileManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first as NSURL

var fileURLs:[NSURL] {
    return (NSFileManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtURL(documentsUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .SkipsHiddenFiles | .SkipsSubdirectoryDescendants | .SkipsPackageDescendants, error: nil) as [NSURL]).sorted{$0.lastPathComponent<$1.lastPathComponent}
}

var myFileNames = fileURLs.map{$0.lastPathComponent!}

println(myFileNames.description) // ["Shared Playground Data"]

"testing".writeToURL(documentsUrl.URLByAppendingPathComponent("test1.txt"), atomically: true, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
"testing2".writeToURL(documentsUrl.URLByAppendingPathComponent("test2.txt"), atomically: true, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)

myFileNames = fileURLs.map{$0.lastPathComponent!}

println(myFileNames.description) // "[Shared Playground Data, test1.txt, test2.txt]"
```